# Turn off caption prefix WITHOUT using caption package

Tags: captions, tufte

How do I remove the caption prefix (i.e Figure 1:, Table 1:) from figures, tables, etc. WITHOUT using the `caption` package? The reason I don't want to is because I'm using `tufte-latex` which already redefines the `\caption` command, so it doesn't work.

**EDIT**: More specifically, if I choose to use the normal `\caption` command, the figure is numbered and shows up in the List of Figures. If I use the alternative approach, the figure is not numbered and doesn't show up in the List of Figures. Same applies for tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you still need the caption to show up in a list of figures or list of tables?  Or is it merely a captioned image in a document that has no requirements to be referenced anywhere else?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Actually, it's kinda specific. I want _only_ the captions and figures that are left numbered to show up in the list. All other should just remain in the document.

Comment: In this case, don't use the `figure` or `table` environments.  Just `\begin{center}<\includegraphics{} or tabular, as needed>\par Here is my non-numbered caption\end{center}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How would that work for `marginfigure` and `margintable` (defined in `tufte-latex`?) Besides, it's a very hack-ish solution and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Please, make your request more precise, stating *what* figures or tables you don't want numbered. “Left numbered” is unclear.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my question to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: I don't have tufte-latex but if I put the caption text in the figure environment without `\caption` this seems to give the desired result.

Comment: @Steve Again, very hackish. Also the text won't show up the in the LOF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some surgery on `tufte-common.def` in order to accommodate for a `\varcaption` command which has the syntax

```
\varcaption[<offset>]{<caption text>}
```

(the optional argument is similar to the second optional argument for `\caption`).

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varcaption}[2][0pt]{%
  \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{-#1}%
  \gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{#2}%
}
\xpatchcmd{\end@tufte@float}
  {\par\vspace}
  {\ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@varcaption}{}}{\@tufte@varcaption{\@tufte@stored@varcaption}}{}\par\vspace}
  {}{}
\xapptocmd{\end@tufte@float}{\gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{}}{}{}
\gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{} % initialize
\newcommand\@tufte@varcaption[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@parboxrestore 
  \if@minipage\@setminipage\fi
  \@tufte@caption@font
  \@tufte@caption@justification
  \noindent #1\par
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
Something
\caption{A numbered caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}
Something
\varcaption{An unnumbered caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

You'll see that the second caption is not listed in the List of Figures.

[image]

A version without `regexpatch`; copy in your document preamble everything from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` (included).

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varcaption}[2][0pt]{%
  \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{-#1}%
  \gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{#2}%
}
\gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{} % initialize
\newcommand\@tufte@varcaption[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@parboxrestore 
  \if@minipage\@setminipage\fi
  \@tufte@caption@font
  \@tufte@caption@justification
  \noindent #1\par
  \endgroup
}
\def\end@tufte@float{%
      \par\hbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\ifthenelse{\prevdepth>0}{\vspace{-\prevdepth}}{}% align baselines of boxes
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % build the caption box
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}%
      \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\marginparwidth}\hbox{}%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@caption}{}}{\@tufte@orig@caption[\@tufte@stored@shortcaption]{\@tufte@stored@caption}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}{\@tufte@orig@label{\@tufte@stored@label}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@varcaption}{}}{\@tufte@varcaption{\@tufte@stored@varcaption}}{}
        \par\vspace{-\prevdepth}%% TODO: DOUBLE-CHECK FOR SAFETY
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % now typeset the stored boxes
    \begin{fullwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\linewidth}%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
          {\@tufte@float@fullwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
          {\@tufte@float@textwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
    \@tufte@orig@endfloat% end original LaTeX float environment
    % output debug info
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@debug}}{%
      \typeout{^^J^^J----------- Tufte-LaTeX float information ----------}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}%
        {\typeout{Warning: Float unlabeled!}}%
        {\typeout{Float label: [\@tufte@stored@label]}}%
      \typeout{Page number: [\thepage]}%
      \def\MessageBreak{^^J}%
      \typeout{\@tufte@float@debug@info}%
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}%
        {\typeout{Symmetric: [true]}}%
        {\typeout{Symmetric: [false]}}%
      \typeout{----------------------------------------------------^^J^^J}%
    }{}%
    % reset commands and temp boxes and captions
    \gdef\@tufte@float@debug@info{}%
    \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
    \let\label\@tufte@orig@label%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@figure@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@caption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@label{}%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{0pt}% reset caption offset
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@varcaption{}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
Something
\caption{A numbered caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}
Something
\varcaption{An unnumbered caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

### Support for `marginfigure` and `margintable`

With the following code that must be added to the previous one before the final `\makeatother`, you can use `\varcaption` also in `marginfigure` and `margintable`.

```
\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \renewcommand\varcaption[2][]{\par\@tufte@varcaption{##2}}%
    \@tufte@caption@font%
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \@tufte@caption@justification%
    \@tufte@margin@par%
    \noindent%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
  }
```

Comment: So what exactly do I need to do? What do I need to copy into my preamble? I copied from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` and included `regexpatch`. I get an `Undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: @eshansingh1 What `Undefined control sequence`?

Comment: Wait no, no longer getting that but there is no caption.

Comment: Ah, wait - this is meant to work with `figure`, not `marginfigure`. Thanks for this though, I can model this to figure something out.

Comment: Also, _how_ did you do all of this so fast? I have absolutely zero knowledge about LaTeX programming. I guess you have to know it pretty well to get to 464k rep.

Comment: @eshansingh1 I looked what `\caption` does in tufte classes and then tried to figure out a way. I'll look into `marginfigure` later. Now I have to teach a LaTeX class. `;-)`

Comment: OK, thanks. Sorry for all the confusion here, I should have handled this question better.

Comment: @eshansingh1 The patch is online

Comment: The "final" `\makeatletter`? There's only one, right?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `\makeatother`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, I told the OP how to add a figure in the text, without numbering.  Here, based on a follow-up comment by the OP, I show how to get the unnumbered figure into the margin, similar to `marginfigure` of the `tufte-book` class.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\noindent\hrulefill

\lipsum[1]
\marginpar{
\includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-A}\par
\footnotesize This is my caption
}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=.5in]{example-image-A}\par
\caption{margin figure}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I'll wait for more answers. In case none come up, I'll accept this.